# WCF To WPF client - Populating the ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, listbox

That is a method for populating ListBox from the data which comes from WCF service.

```
private void FillListbox()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            client.Open();
            listBox.ItemsSource = client.GetAllProducts();            
        }
```

But in the ListBox all i can see is

```
ProductListClient.ServiceReference1.Product
```

Therefore i have added an override ToString() method in my model, but still i can not see my data in the ListBox. How can i fix that?

Comment: Methods are not part of the serialization process so your ToString override is not present client side. You would have to extract the type into a shared datacontract library or do what Maxim says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the binding is working and your list contain items. Now you need to implement ItemDataTemplate in your ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myTodoList}}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Ignore the naming of my example. you need to adapt to the names of objects in your application

Comment: Thanx @ Maxim Fleitling